# deleting identical rows in a vector of vector

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector

assume that I have an integer vector of vector `vector<vector<int >v1` . and I m trying to delete the identical rows that have same elements. Such as

```
before    after
--v1--   --v1'--
 1324     1324
 1324     2435
 2435
 2435
```

the task is deleting repeated rows.
Here is a very simple algorithm for it , bu I need C++ version ??

```
for (int i = 0; i < v1.size(); i++)
      {
         for (int j = 1; j < v1.size() ; j++ )
            {
               for (int a=0; v1[i][a] == v1 [j][a]; a++)  
               {
                   if (a=v1.end());
                   {
                    //erase(the row);                    

                   } 
               }


            }
       }
```

Answer (score 2):

If the outer vector is sorted then you can use standard algorithm std::unique
For example

```
v1.erase( std::unique( v1.begin(), v1.end() ), v1.end() );
```

I would like to append that provided that inner vectors are also sorted. Otherwise you should use the same algorithm std::unique with a predicate that will sort inner vectors before comparing them.

Comment: On this website, we do not answer "Give me the codez" questions.

Comment: if the case that row lengths are changing at each row and they are not sorted

Comment: I m sorry, I dont want ask like "give me the code " question. just a simple way would be enough or an analytic explanation.

Comment: @DeadMG: And it's not an enough reason to downvote an answer!

Comment: I disagree. This answer isn't helpful- it encourages bad questioning behaviour. On the strictest level, I can issue a downvote for whatever reason I want, whenever I want.

Comment: @zaratushtra: I had an answer, I hope it works for you. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19483557/952747)

Comment: @vlad from Moscow the vector is not sorted. and the task is not deleting repeated elements in the same row.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand your question, you have a 2D array and you want delete the rows which have equal columns:

```
vector<vector<int>> v1
{
    {1, 1},   // Should be removed
    {2, 7},
    {3, 3},   // Should be removed
    {4},
    {5, 5, 5} // Should be removed
};

for (auto r = v1.begin(); r != v1.end(); )
{
    if (r->size() < 2)
        continue;

    auto k = r->front();

    bool equal = all_of(r->begin(), r->end(), [&k](int x)
    {
        return x==k;
    });

    if (equal)
        r = v1.erase(r);
    else
        ++r;
}
```

[Live code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84ca7e16971b6cfc)

---

```
   before        after
 ----v1---     ---v1'---
 {1,3,2,4}     {1,3,2,4}
 {1,3,2,4}     {2,4,3,5}
 {2,4,3,5}
 {2,4,3,5}
```

Reading you comment, it'd better to show your table as above to stop misleading about the problem. So in this case you can use `unique` function:

```
v1.erase(unique(v1.begin(), v1.end()), v1.end());
```

Comment: @M M. you miss understood the task is deleting repeated rows.

Comment: in your example none of the row are identical. so you dont need to delete any row. lets suppose you have another {1,1}, this case you should delete one of the {1,1}